# Why the * regular expression indicates what can or cannot be it's previous character

Tags: regex

Take this for an example which I found in some blog, 
"How about searching for apple word which was spelled wrong in a given file where apple is misspelled as ale, aple, appple, apppple, apppppple etc. To find all patterns

```
grep 'ap*le' filename
```

Readers should observe that the above pattern will match even ale word as * indicates 0 or more of previous character occurrence."

Now it's saying that "ale" will be accept when we are having `ap*le`, isn't the "ap" and "le" fixed?

Comment: Be careful (you have tagged your question bash): a regular expression is different from a shell wildcard. (A `*` in bash is approximately `.*` in regular expressions: any sequence of characters, including none at all.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*` is a [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) meaning 0 or more times *for the previous pattern* -- in this case a single literal `p`. You can also state the same as `*` with a quantifier:

```
 ap{0,}le
```

The interesting question sometimes is 'what is the previous pattern?' It is often helpful to put a pattern in a group to aid understand of what the 'previous pattern' is.

Consider wanting to find any of:

```
 ale, aple, appple, apppple, apppppple, able, abbbbbbble
```

Your first try might be:

```
 /ap|b*le/ 

   ^     literal 'p' is the first alternative  #WRONG regex will use 'ap'
    ^   or
     ^  literal 'b'
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gG2wB3/2)

What you want in this case is:

```
 /a(?:p|b)*le/
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gG2wB3/3)

If you do not want to match `ale` and only match aple, appple, apppple, apppppple, use the `+` instead of the `*` which means one or more:

```
/ap+le/
```

And is equivalent to `/ap{1,}le/`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gG2wB3/4)

And if you want to only match aple, appple and leave out the variants with more than 3 'p's use the additional max quantifier:

```
/ap{1,3}le/
```

All the variants above will match `apple` correctly spelled. If you what only aple, appple, and not match apple, use [alteration](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):

```
/a(?:p|p{3})le/
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gG2wB3/5)

Comment: Thanks! Will   ls -l | grep "ap.*le"    will have the same effect as   ls -l | grep ap+le     The output that I want am getting by using  ls -l | grep "ap.*le    only.

Comment: No, since the `.` can be any character. So  `grep "ap.*le"` would match `aple, apple, apXle, ap=le, ap le` etc. The `+` is 1 or more of the previous pattern, in this case a literal `p`

Comment: Thankyou So much. That clears my doubts. And I am kind afraid to ask this because this does not belong here, how can I markup my commands in comments? I tried <pre><code>xxx</pre></code> I is not working and I am totally new to stack overflow. I did look up markup manuals.

Comment: Use a back tick for code like markup and *italics* and **bold** with one or two `*` around the text

Answer (score 0):

No its not.

"*" in your case means zero or any occurrence of p. While a and le is fixed. If you need fixed ap and le then this is what you need:

```
ap+le
```

"+" means at least once but no limit on number of occurrences.

This means now any number of p after a but before l. So it wont select `ale` now.

Comment: "+" needs to be escaped in BRE `grep` (default `grep`), otherwise it's a literal "+". Using `-E` or `egrep` (ERE) does not require escaping.